# Passing a point in to a function

Tags: c++, pointers

In this program I've created two pointers (a,b) that points to the memory address of x and y. In the function I've created its supposed to swap the memory address of a and b(So b=a and a=b). When I compile it gives me a error (invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*') What does that mean? I'm passing a pointer to the function or is it read it as a regular int?

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
void pointer(int* x,int* y)// Swaps the memory address to a,b
{
    int *c;
    *c = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = *c;
}

int main()
{
    int x,y;
    int* a = &x;
    int* b = &y;
    cout<< "Adress of a: "<<a<<" Adress of b: "<<b<<endl; // Display both memory address

    pointer(*a,*b);
    cout<< "Adress of a: "<<a<<" Adress of b: "<<b<<endl; // Displays the swap of memory address  

    return 0;
}
```

error message:

> C++.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>       C++.cpp:20:16: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
>       C++.cpp:6:6: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'void pointer(int*, int*)' [-fpermissive]
>       C++.cpp:20:16: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
>       C++.cpp:6:6: error:   initializing argument 2 of 'void pointer(int*, int*)' [-fpermissive]

Comment: Do you actually want to swap the values the pointers are pointing to or swap the addresses of the variables? Just asking, because as Vlad pointed out, atm you are swapping the values and this could be done without any pointers (which is much nicer IMHO)

Comment: I'm swapping the memory address.

Comment: Well, thats interesting. Maybe I just do not get it, but I have problems to understand how this could be used. Isnt it like this: Any pointer that was pointing to `a` before will point to `b` after the swap. Thus it has practically the same effect as swapping the values, or am I too confused??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this function call

```
pointer(*a,*b);
```

expressions `*a` and `*b` have type `int` while the corresponding parameters of the function have type `int *`.

If you want to swap two pointers and not the values (objects x and y) pointed to by the pointers then
 the function should look the following way

```
void pointer( int **x, int **y )// Swaps the memory address to a,b
{
    int *c = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = c;
}
```

And called like

```
pointer( &a, &b );
```

Or you could define the parameters as having reference types. For example

```
void pointer( int * &x, int * &y )// Swaps the memory address to a,b
{
    int *c = x;
    x = y;
    y = c;
}
```

And call it like

```
pointer( a, b );
```

Comment: Thank you everyone! I was stumped!

Comment: Better still, call your function something like `pointerSwap()` rather than the very uninformative `pointer()`

Comment: @Robin Hartland  It is not my function.:) I would use std::swap.:)

Comment: @Robin Hartland How to determine whether somebody can program to an intermediate level in C++?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow Well I'm not a complete noob :) One step up from beginner is intermediate, right? I'm aware there's a whole universe of C++ness out there, for "advanced", "expert", "legendary", and "Jon Skeet" people to explore.

Comment: Ahh thanks again I'll be more accurate with naming my functions. I could used the swap function but that would have been too easy! xD.

Answer (score 3):

`*a` and `*b` are of type `int`, while `a` and `b` are both of type `int*`. Your function takes two `int*`'s, so all you have to do is change

```
pointer(*a,*b);
```

to

```
pointer(a,b);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are passing `*x` arguments -> it means that you are dereferencing the pointers, and passing the value of memory place where a and b are pointing to.

The solution is to pass the pointers, so usual `a` and `b` since they are already the pointers:
`pointer(a,b)`

Answer (score 0):

Both Pointers `*a` & `*b` are integers.
But The Variables `a` & `b` are `*int`s.
Not getting them confused together...you have to change your `pointer()` function to:

```
pointer(a, b);
```

what this does, it **Passes** the pointers.since `a` and `b` are already the pointers, because both are `*int`s.